# react-360 did not create project

Tags: reactjs, npm, virtual-reality, react-360

I installed react-360 using `npm install -g react-360-cli`.

But `react-360 init Hello` did not create any directory.

I am using ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Any errors you have encountered?

1) You could be having permission issues while trying to install packages in node_modules folder. Try changing the permission to the folder like:

sudo chown -R USERNAME /FILE_PATH

2) Try updating node version if 1st doesn't work.